# byte length and offset for k3d3/ed25519 byte[] variables?

Tags: performance, ed25519

I've discovered for myself that java's `BigInteger` is very slow, so I'm trying to weakly optimize [this java implementation of ed25519](https://github.com/k3d3/ed25519-java) which I will fork and post if successful by substituting `BigInteger` with jscience's [`LargeInteger`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html).

I'm almost done converting all of the `BigInteger`s to `LargeInteger`s, but [I still need an equivalent to `BigInteger`'s `and`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288559/largeintegers-equivalent-of-bigintegers-and), and I need to know how long some `byte[]` variables should be and their offsets to use [`valueOf`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html#valueOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) with `byte[]`s.

I could keep some of the existing code and merely [convert `BigInteger`s to `LargeInteger`s](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html#valueOf%28java.math.BigInteger%29), but I'd prefer to fully replace `BigInteger`.

["length - the maximum number of bytes to read."](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html#valueOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) sounds like I should use `.length` of the `byte[]` to be converted.  Is that correct?  If not, what should be used?

["offset - the offset at which to start reading the bytes."](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html#valueOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) sounds like I should use `0`.  Is that correct?  If not, what should be used?

I'm 100% new to binary and cryptography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every Java `.valueOf(byte[] s, int offset, int length)` has the same meaning:

- `s` is the array to read from.
- `offset` is the location in the array to start reading from (inclusive).
- `length` is the number of bytes to try and read - "try" because the array may not be long enough to have that many bytes from `offset`.

Remembering that Java arrays are zero-indexed, `.valueOf(z, offset, length)` will read from every byte from `s[offset]` to `s[offset+length-1]`. However, if `offset+length > s.length`, then every byte from `s[offset]` to `s[s.length]` will be read.

As an example, if we have `byte[] s = new byte[] {10, 20, 30, 15, 4}`, then:

- `LargeInteger.valueOf(s, 0, 5)` will use all five bytes.
- `LargeInteger.valueOf(s, 1, 3)` will use bytes `{20, 30, 15}`.
- `LargeInteger.valueOf(s, 3, 7)` will use bytes `{15, 4}`.

In Ed25519, the length and offset you use will depend on what part of the byte[] you need to access. For example, initially you take a seed `k` and hash it to get `h = H(k)`, which you then split into a LHS and RHS. You could convert the LHS and RHS independently into `LargeInteger`s with `LargeInteger.valueOf(h, 0, b/8)` for the LHS, and `LargeInteger.valueOf(h, b/8, b/4-b/8)` for the RHS.

So the end answer is, in most cases yes, you will use `offset = 0` and `length = s.length`. And it looks like you can directly replace `BigInteger.valueOf()` with `LargeInteger.valueOf()`.